# Unable to define width of absolute container's children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to define the width of a few divs nested within an absolute parent. Their width is defined but does not appear to be taken in consideration by the browser.
Any ideas of what it is I am missing (or doing wrong)?
Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

HTML

```
<div class="icons-container">
  <div>
    <img src="img/2d.svg" alt="2d animation icon">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/3d.svg" alt="3d animation icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icons-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.icons-container div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.icons-container div img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `.inline` to `.inline-block`:

```css
.icons-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.icons-container div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.icons-container div img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons-container">
  <div>
    <img src="img/2d.svg" alt="2d animation icon">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="img/3d.svg" alt="3d animation icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use display inline-block instead of inline

Comment: thank you very much simoncereska, that worked just fine!